# How to check if all arguments equal the same thing and return a string

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement

I am wanting to join the arguments (all strings) that are passed in to my function together with a delimiter of ' | ', but if they are all empty strings, then to just pass an empty string.

I have the following:

```
constructString(one: string, two: string, three: string) {
  if (one === '' && two === '' && three === '') {
    return '';
  }
  return [one, two, three].filter(Boolean).join('|')
}
```

My question is...  Is there a simpler, more elegant way of performing this, or some useful function that JS has that I am missing in order to perform this task?

Comment: Just remove the first three lines of the function?

Comment: ^^ since `[one, two, three].filter(Boolean).join('|')` will result in `""` if they're all blank. @CertainPerformance - That's an answer, not a comment. :-)

Comment: @CertainPerformance - I'd tried that already, but I got a returned string of '' | | undefined' in my test...

Comment: For a result like that, sounds like the input strings aren't empty, then?

Comment: The strings being passed in are determined by ternary to be either the desired value or '';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use of `...` operator

```js
function constructString(...args) {
  if (args.every(x => x === '')) {
     return '';
  }
  
  return args.join('|');
}

console.log('[', constructString('a', 'b', 'c'), ']');

console.log('[', constructString('', '', ''), ']');
```

---

**For the minimalist lovers**

```js
function constructString(...args) {
  return args.every(x => x === '') ? '' : args.join('|');
}

console.log('[', constructString('a', 'b', 'c'), ']');

console.log('[', constructString('', '', ''), ']');
```

Comment: I was looking at how to use the multiple args feature but couldn't find online how to use it properly. Thanks for the advice. Works like a charm. Also appreciate the minimalist version ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `filter` only for `Boolean` values which works for blank values too as they are filtered out.

```js
function constructString(one, two, three) {
  
  return [one, two, three].filter(Boolean).join('|')
}
//with Boolean values as string
console.log(constructString('true', 'false', 'true'));

//with blank values as string
console.log(constructString('', '', ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```js
function constructString(one, two, three) {
  if (one === '' && two === '' && three === '') {
    return '';
  }
  return [one, two, three].filter(Boolean).join('|')
}

console.log('result :',constructString('String-1','String-1','String-1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> if they are all empty strings, then to just pass an empty string.

You can use the arguments object and create array from it and check if all of them are `''` using `Array.every` which will return true or false. If all are empty then return `''`

Otherwise is the argument contain mix of empty string and non empty string then filter out the empty string and join with delimiter

```js
function constructString() {
  let crtArry = Array.from(arguments).every(function(item) {
    return item === '';
  });
  if (crtArry) {
    return 'Returning empty String' + '';
  } else {
    return Array.from(arguments).filter((item) => {
      return item !== '';
    }).join('|')
  }
}

console.log(constructString('', '', ''))
console.log(constructString('2', '3', ''))
```